# Cannot access phpmyadmin xampp from public ip address windows 8

Tags: ip, public

I have setup the xampp that is available for private network but the problem is with public access to my xampp folder we are set of php developers and far away from each other i have allow the firewall to access my xampp and  apache server but not working on public ip address need little help what to do next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well in short if you can access the xampp on local network it means you have configured the firewall to access your xammp and apache server.
First if you dont have static ip or if you have i prefer to go to http://www.noip.com and make account than click on add a host and than select Port 80 Redirect
you will get your public ip automatically and than add a host it will take upto five minute to start working and it will keep track of your dynamic ip don't worry about dynamic ip.
Than Go to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.
Open the host file add as given below. 
127.0.0.1 yourhostname.zapto.org.
Save the file and done.
I hope you will be able to access your xampp and local website with public ip.

Comment: always be in your services where ever you get stuck i am here